# Testing for View Exceptions in Rails with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

How do I write a test that would iterate through all the instances of User#Show (for each User) to see if a exception is thrown?

I understand how to write a test to check if the object has certain data in it. 
But don`t know how to iterate for each while making sure that it wouldn't throw a 500 error etc.

I might just have temp. brain freeze, but please help me out.

Any helps or guidelines are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "view exceptions"? Errors thrown by your view? Are you wanting to write a controller test (which you can test for a 500 status error) or a view test (which you can use to just test the view in isolation)? What do you mean by "all instances of User#show"?

Comment: I looking to write a controller that goes through each User (Steve, Joe etc.) using User#Show & checks for a 500 error or raised exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. This assumes you have already created and saved users to your database.

```
describe UsersController do
  User.each do |user|
    it "doesn't return a 500 error for user #{user.name}" do
      get :show, :id => user.id
      assert_response(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Your Ruby code doesn't just have to be inside of an `it` so you can use that to loop and then perform `it`s later on.